# Can an HTML element have both an ID and a Class?

Tags: javascript, html, class, events

I was wondering if you can use both an ID and a Class in an HTML element.

For example an ID for individual styling.
And then a class for duplicate event handling on multiple elements

Comment: @LearnerBeware: please next time do some research before posting a QUESTION. have a look here it might help --> http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/

dont forget to mark the answer as Helpful to help the users coming later find the correct answer easily. thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! please refer to [this LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to help you better understand our community and our rules for asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible no problem in it. The class can be used for more than one elements and id should be unique (one Element one Id).
i.e `<div id='myDiv' class='myClass'></div>` is correct and has no Problem you can have another Div like `<div id='myDiv2' class='myClass'></div>`

Comment: provide an example maybe... `<div id='myDiv' class='myClass1 myClass2'></div>`

Comment: I was editing the answer when you did this comment. Thanks. Is it Ok now ?

Comment: I didn't downvote you... I was just trying to make things a little more complete.  OP could have really easily googled this anyway...

Comment: I just told the situation :-).